# Error in AplicationContext schema in Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I'm starting to do a Spring Application using Spring Tool Suite. I have an error in my app when I add the line

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

in my Application Context schema.
This is the error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    TypeError occured processing XML 'org/springframework/web/accept/ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean'. See Error Log for more details  app-config.xml  /springapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring   line 15 Spring Beans Problem
```

I have looked for and trying with differents solutions, but the error persists.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.vincle</groupId>
 <artifactId>springapp</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>springapp Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <dependencies>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.11</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<build>
  <finalName>springapp</finalName>
 </build>
 <properties>
 <org.springframework.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
  <java-version>1.7</java-version>
  <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
   <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
 </properties>
</project>
```

And this is my web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>Springapp</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.vincle.springapp.web" />

 <mvc:annotation-driven/>


 </beans>
```

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: paste here applicationContext.xml

Comment: Did you added the mvc namespace in your xml  `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"` and `schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"`

Comment: When do you have the error? in STS/Eclipse or during startup?

Comment: I have the error in STS. However, the application run correctly in the server.

Answer (score 1):

I have the answer:

In the pom.xml, i have these dependecies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

However, the version of the SpringFramework that I had defined was 3.2.2. When I have changed the version of these dependencies to 3.2.2, The problem was removed.

Thanks!!